# sending and receiving array in MPI C

Tags: c, mpi

Here's how my code should work. Slave nodes will perform some computations, and each node will send a value, minE with a corresponding linear array, phi. Root node will then receive, 2 values. I'm trying to figure out on how I will store **N-1** (number of slaves) **phi** in root node. I tried accepting **phi** in a 2D array but it doesn't work. Or maybe, I'm doing it wrong. So this code simply receives the values of phi from the last node to send.

```
if (world_rank == root) {
    for(i=1; i<world_size; i++) {
        MPI_Irecv(&local_minE[i], 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rcv_request[i]);
        MPI_Irecv(phi, len, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rcv_request[i]); 
        MPI_Waitall(world_size-1, &rcv_request[1], &status[1]);
    }   
    MPI_Waitall(world_size-1, &rcv_request[1], &status[1]);  
}
else {
   //after computations, node will send a value, minE with a corresponding array phi
   MPI_Isend(&minE, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&send_request[0]);
   MPI_Isend(phi, len, MPI_INT, root, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request[0]);
   MPI_Wait(&send_request[0], &status[0]);
}
```

Comment: Can you create an example that actually runs?

Comment: clarified my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should consider using `MPI_Gather()` or even `MPI_Igather()` if the non-blocking aspect is important for you.

Now, for what regards your code snippet, there is a fundamental problem: you try to use `phi` on the receiving part while it hasn't been received yet. You need to alter you code so that you first do the waiting part, and only after you do the copying / transposition part.

This would look something like this:

```
int *trphi = malloc(len*world_size*sizeof(int));
for(i=0; i<world_size; i++) {
    MPI_Irecv(trphi[i], len, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rcv_request[i]);
}
MPI_Waitall(world_size-1, &rcv_request[1], &status[1]);
for(i=1; i<world_size; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<len; j++) {
        rphi[j][i] = trphi[i][j];
    }
}
for(j=0; j<len; j++) {
    rphi[j][O] = phi[j];
}
free(trphi);
```

But again, look at `MPI_Gather()` (and possibly also a good `MPI_Datatype`) to do it much more nicely.